# unit decomposition

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

> Find unit decomposition of multiplication operator $(Ax)(t) = \sin(t)\,x(t)$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ space.

I started from spectrum of operator $\sigma(A)=[-1,1] \implies
E_\lambda \lambda=E(-\infty,\lambda)= 0$, if $\lambda<-1$ and
$E_\lambda \lambda=I$, if $\lambda>1$. $E$ is projection-valued measure.

Then $f$ is continuous function. $f(A)\,x(t) = f(\sin(t))\,x(t)$.

Taking the limit $f(t) \to \chi_{(-\infty,\lambda)}(t)$,
from this moment I didn't understand:

We have
$$
E_\lambda: x(t) \mapsto \chi_{[-\arcsin(\lambda) + \pi + 2\pi n, \arcsin(\lambda) + 3\pi +2\pi n]}(t)
$$
because restriction of $\chi_{(-\infty,\lambda)}(\sin(t))$ to $[-1,1]$ equals to
$$
\sum\chi_{[-\arcsin(\lambda) + \pi + 2\pi n, \arcsin(\lambda) + 3\pi + 2\pi n]}(t)
$$
and the answer is
$$
E_\lambda x(t) = \begin{cases}
0, &\lambda \leq - 1 \\
\sum\chi_{[-\arcsin(\lambda) + \pi + 2\pi n, \arcsin(\lambda) + 3\pi + 2\pi n]}(t), &-1 < \lambda \leq 1 \\x(t), &\lambda > 1
\end{cases}
$$

So I didn't understand how Indicator of $\sin(x)$ ($\chi_{(-\infty,\lambda)}$) restricted to
$$
\sum\chi_{[-\arcsin(\lambda) + \pi + 2\pi n, \arcsin(\lambda) + 3\pi + 2\pi n]}(t).
$$

Why borders changed to $[-\arcsin(\lambda) + \pi + 2\pi n, \arcsin(\lambda) + 3\pi + 2\pi n]$?

P.S. Sorry for my English, I'm not native speaker.